# Separate files by its types but keeping the directory structure

Tags: file, directory

I have a complex directory structure with 30.000 files that contains various filetype files:

```
    ...2014
    .......01
    .........File1.jpg
    .........File2.mpg
    .......02
    .........FileA.jpg
    .........FileB.mpg
```

Now I want to separate the files by filetype, but keep the directory structure.

Result:

```
    JPG
    ...2014
    .......01
    .........File1.jpg
    .......02
    .........FileA.jpg
    MPG
    ...2014
    .......01
    .........File2.mpg
    .......02
    .........FileB.mpg
```

How do I do that on Windows 10 ?

Comment: What language? What interface? What have you tried? What?

Comment: Are you looking for programming help or a software recommendation?

Comment: Is there a Software available for this task ? It could work a bit similar to Treesize software.